# How to use onchange event when drop down in search based

Tags: jquery, html

I have used select2 jquery in my code for search drop down, but when I used this my onchange event is not working.

**My code is:**

```
<script>
$('#regno').on("change", function (e) {
    alert('hello');
})
 </script>
 <div>
      <label>Registration No.</label>
                        <select id=\"regno\" name=\"regno\" class=\"form- control select2 \" aria-hidden=\"true\">
       <option value="0">Select</option>
       <option value="1">Phoenix Beverages</option>
       </select>
       </div>

<script>
$('.select2').select2();
</script>
```

Please guide me how to resolve this.

Comment: what does `select2` do? And did you check your console for errors?

Comment: select2 is plugin using for search base dropdown,and not showing any error in console

Comment: Your order of things are incorrect. First declare the select in HTML then call select2 then add the event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [select2's documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events).

To achieve your goal, you should first find your select2 element, make jQuery recognize the element as a select2 element and then write code for the change event.

```
var $eventSelect = $("#regno");

$eventSelect.select2();

$eventSelect.on("change", function(e) {
    // insert your code here
});
```

Edit: you almost made it work. The order of your jQuery code was just not right.

Comment: Also the part of the script was before the element even existed